# How to change browser url box's text by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page it contain a button when i click the button it will set some text in web brower url box.(exam it set text "www.google.com" Is it possible in java script?

Comment: You can't do it.  It's a security issue.  If you were able to then I could tell you you're at facebook.com and steal your password.  Or is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: hi ehudokai, I accepted your point i tried to know this feature have java script or not ? thats all.

Comment: @Tvm Murthy Trying to think positive: what's the point of your system? I mean, when a user willingly presses that infamous url changing button, what does he need to expect? I'm putting myself in the user's point of view, I'm curious about this thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, That's not possible as far as I know. You can't change the address from address bar of a browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
```

Probably not what you meant though ;)

Comment: No i dont need navigate to google just i need full this text in web browser url's box only anyway thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: @TvmMurthy In that case, see @Sarfraz's answer